# How to get the machine memory allocation of domU in Xen

Tags: virtualization, xen

I have known that there would be a physical-to-machine map of domU in mode HVM, and I want to get the `memory address` on a machine of the specific domU. 
Because I want to simulate what would happen in the system when a bit reverse happened on the memory. I want to know the `memory address` on a machine of the specific domU, and reverse a random bit on this address area, then see the results in this virtualized system.

I want to know how can I get this `memory address` of the specific domU without changing the source code of Xen. Or any advice to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tools/xenpaging/, which grabs a single page of memory for a HVM domU.

It will help you to understand how to obtain a memory address within domU, how to obtain a pointer to physical memory, and how to modify it.